# how to set default prefetch row size in tomcat for oracle connection

Tags: oracle, tomcat, oracle11g, prefetch

Hi I want to be able to set defaultRowPrefetch in tomcat server configuration.

If it is possible, i want to programmatic avoid setting default prefetch row.

Example: 
    (OracleConnection(conn)).setRowPrefetch(20);

However, I want to set the default row prefetch variable in tomcat server.xml configuration.

```
<Resource
            name="myDataSource"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            password="#######"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    <!-- more information -->
    />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use attribute "connectionProperties" of Resource tag documented here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html.
The connection property to set is "defaultRowPrefetch".

Your configuration will be:

```
<Resource
        name="myDataSource"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        password="#######"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        connectionProperties="defaultRowPrefetch=20"
<!-- more information -->
/>
```

To check configuration you can invoke:
(OracleConnection(conn)).getDefaultRowPrefetch();